# Modin[dask] on Apple M1 chip

Tags: pandas, dask, apple-m1, modin

I have successfully installed modin[dask] with conda on my Apple M1 chip MacBook Pro, but when I run the code, I got the below errors:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ncores'.

The below is pip list(Python 3.10.4):

```
dask                          2022.5.0
distributed                   2022.5.0
modin                         0.11.3
pandas                        1.3.4
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please include your complete traceback and installation steps.

Comment: Actually, I could install modin[dask] successfully with `conda install modin[dask]`, but when I run it, it prompts the above exception message.

Comment: `modin[dask]` is NOT the name of a conda package https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/0.12.1/installation.html#installing-with-conda and https://anaconda.org/search?q=modin

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to diagnose what's going on without seeing what code you ran and exactly how you installed everything.

Here's a blog post about setting up an M1-based Mac with dask:
https://coiled.io/blog/apple-arm64-mambaforge/

The key points are:

- start fresh with mambaforge
- conda should be ok if mamba's not an options
- install *everything* into a fresh environment and *everything* should come from the conda-forge channel.

```
mamba create --name=dask-env python=3.9 dask dask-labextension --channel=conda-forge
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Paul. I will try these key points, but I have to use Python 3.10.4 because of some reasons.

Comment: @Joycode you can try 3.10. It should work. Python 3.9 is still my "default"